# How do I summon an armor stand with arms that will work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building a mansion to impress my friends.

I've seen pictures of armor stands with ARMS. I searched how to summon one but all of them were either 1.9 or beta. (?how?)

What command do i use to summon one that works?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Armor stands were added in PC version 1.8 and when you put armor on them they always have arms. AFAIK, they've always worked that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can watch [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoLRLKyswTI) (by Sethbling) to see how to show arms and more

But if you want to show arms, try: `/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {ShowArms:1}`

If you already spawned a ArmorStand and want to add arms (show arms), you can do: `/entitydata @e[r=2,type=ArmorStand] {ShowArms:1}` (tested).

Answer (score 0):

ArmorStands with the `ShowArms:1b` tag will have arms:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {ShowArms:1b}
```

You could also set this tag on the closest already-placed ArmorStands like so:

```
/entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand,c=1] {ShowArms:1b}
```